# Xpath expression to get first parent that meets criteria

Tags: .net, xml, xpath

I have an XML file simplified for this example that looks similar to this:

```
<Item>
  <Item> <- The one I want
    <Value>Test</Value>
    <AnotherTag>
        <Value>Test2</Value>
    </AnotherTag>
  </Item>

  <Item>
    <Value>Test</Value>
    <AnotherTag>
        <Value>Test3</Value>
    </AnotherTag>
  </Item>
</Item>
```

I am trying to get the first child `Item` node based on it's children which I have marked in the example above, I have the following expressions which works:

```
var path = "//Item[.//Value='Test'][.//Value='Test2']";
```

My issue is this expression in the above example will also return me the parent Item node in which the conditions are also true. How can I write this to only get the Node in which I have pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 3.0, use the innermost() function:

```
innermost(//Item[.//Value='Test'][.//Value='Test2'])
```